# Syncing your app calendar with google/outlook calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a platform which allows artists to book appointments with Venues, basically rent their space. 
As its a platform there are many venues that sign up with us.

We have our own calendar using full calendar.

I plan to integrate with Google calendar through calendar api for the venue, so all appointments done with us get synced with the venue, i m just stuck with how the authentication will work, because I plan to sync the calendar with a background process, it needs to be a 2 way communication, they change anything on their Google calendar it syncs with our calendar too.

From what I see online, usually we sync calendars for the users that are logged in not for others.

Comment: have you already looked at the official google calendar section of the documentation? 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

Comment: are the calendars for each venue held in separate Google accounts? Or are they all sub-calendars within one account? Basically if you're updating in the background then likely you want a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) style connection rather than using conventional OAuth which requires user interaction periodically. If you control the google accounts then you can set it up easily yourself. If you don't, you'll have to request credentials from the owners.

Comment: yes it's a platform so we can have many venues with their calendars, I wanted to avoid storing their credentials on our side, maybe a token.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you'll need to authenticate each Venue's calendar account (Google/Outlook calendar, most likely) using OAuth 2.0, and then allow Artists to book events based on the Venue's availability.

You can do the actual availability checks and booking queries through the Google/Outlook calendar APIs. You'll need to expose availability through your own app for artists to book times.

If you'd like a pre-built solution, check out the [Kloudless Calendar API](https://developers.kloudless.com/docs/v1/calendar) for an abstraction layer that lets you connect to any Venue's calendaring account through a single implementation, and the open-source [Meeting Scheduler](https://github.com/kloudless/meeting-scheduler) built on Kloudless as an easy way to prompt artists to select a free time slot in a Venue's calendar. Kloudless also supports sync through the Activity Monitoring features. (Disclosure: I'm CTO of Kloudless)

Comment: Hey vinod, what's your pricing for say 1000 users?

Comment: @user1393503 Happy to chat about it. Do you mind shooting over an email to hello [at] kloudless.com?